# Prime number function with Haskel

Tags: functions, programming

> Given a natural number $n> 0$, define a function `IsPrime(n)` that tells whether it is, or not, a prime number.

I tried do two functions:

```
HasDivider(x,y) | FALSE if y = 1
                | TRUE if mod(x,y) = 0
                | HasDivider(x, y-1) if mod(x,y) > 0

IsPrime(n) | TRUE if HasDivider(n, n/2) = FALSE
           | FALSE if HasDivider(n, n/2) = TRUE
```

There is any error? or other way to do?

Comment: While I can sort of see the similarities, this is simply not Haskell code at all. Have you tried compiling it and testing it?

Answer (score 2):

There are ***many*** of issues with the code sample you have provided, beyond the fact that it is mathematically unsound. I would encourage you to post this on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com) for feedback concerning your use of Haskell.

Consider the value of `IsPrime` at $n=2$. Is it not true that $2 \equiv 0 \pmod{1}$? Or in Haskell,

```
2 `mod` 1 == 0
```

Hence, as written, your function will find `2` to be a composite number.

---

In case it proves helpful, the following summarizes a few of the issues with you Haskell sample.

1. The syntax for function declarations is `HasDivider x y`, not `HasDivider(x,y)`
2. Likewise, for function calls its `HasDivider a b` not `HasDivider(a,b)`
3. The `Bool` constants are `True` and `False`, not `TRUE` and `FALSE`
4. The operator `/` performs floating point division. You want integer division, which uses `div`.
5. While not explicitly incorrect, you should be mindful of the [difference between `rem` and `mod`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891140/difference-between-mod-and-rem-in-haskell). For you purposes, `rem` should be preferred, as it is generally faster.
6. Your pattern matching uses completely invalid syntax.
7. Your pattern matching is non-exhaustive.
8. `if` does not exist in the way you are trying to use it.
9. You are making the compiler infer all types.

Your (still inefficient) function might resemble the following in valid Haskell

```
hasDivider :: Integral a => a -> a -> Bool
hasDivider _  1 = False
hasDivider x y = x `mod` y == 0 ||  hasDivider x (y-1)

isPrime :: Integral a => a -> Bool
isPrime n = not $ hasDivider n (n `div` 2)

main :: IO ()
main = print $ isPrime 2
```